# Switch and adding char values to array

Tags: c++, char, switch-statement

I have problem with giving new char valure to array. I don't know why I get sign "<" even when n is 12? My program should change expression `int char* tab = "93+"` to one value in this case `12`.

```
    char* tab = "93+";
    int b = sizeof (tab);
    char* tmp = new char[b] ;
    tmp [b-1] = '\0';


if(isdigit(tab[i]) && isdigit(tab[i+1]) ){
               int n;             
               if(tab[i+2]=='+' || tab[i+2]=='-' || tab[i+2]=='*'){

                  switch(tab[i+2]){
                    case '+':   
                    n = (tab[i]-'0') + (tab[i+1]-'0');

                    break;

                    case '-':
                    n = (tab[i]-'0') - (tab[i+1]-'0');
                    break;

                    case '*':
                    n = (tab[i]-'0') * (tab[i+1]-'0');
                    break;
                  }
                  tmp[i] = n+'0'; // I should have 12 but I get <
               }

               else if (tab[i+2]!='+' || tab[i+2]!='-' || tab[i+2]!='*'){
                     goto LAB;
               }
}
```

Comment: Just so you know, `sizeof(tab)` will always be the size of a pointer, not the number of characters it points to, so that's wrong.  `sizeof(some_array)` will give you the number of elements, `sizeof(char*)` is what you are doing.

Comment: So use `strlen(tab)`. Also strings given in `""` are automatically '\0' delimited.

Comment: There's a very high probability you can use something better than a goto.

Comment: @0A0D http://ideone.com/voIEB I guess you were wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
tmp[i] = n+'0'; // I should have 12 but I get <
```

n is 12, but 12 + '0' != '12', since '12' isn't a character. You're putting into tmp[i] the char whose ascii value is 12 more than '0', which is '<'.
I believe declaring (and treating) tmp as an int would be better for your purposes.

Also note that `sizeof (tab)` is the same as `sizeof (char *)`, and not `sizeof ("93+")`, so you're likely to always get `b==4` (in 32-bit machines).

Comment: I try to write: `(char)n` or jut `n` but it is same effect.

Comment: As it should be - the casting happens automatically. However, '12' isn't a character. If you look at an ascii table, you'll see that `'0' == 48`, which means that `'0' + 12 == 60`, and `'<' == 60`.  
Here's an ascii table as an example: http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif

Answer (score 0):

You indeed should get '<'. Here is why: `tmp` is an array of chars. You calculated n to be 12. This is correct. You then added '0' which is 48. 48 + 12 = 60. So you store 60 in tmp[i].
An ASCII 60 is '<'.

You could use an `int tmp`, and not add the '0', and you would get then 12 in tmp[i].